# How to connect to Meteor's MongoDB instance using NetBeans?

Tags: mongodb, netbeans, database-connection, database

I'm doing web development with Meteor, with runs MongoDB and [minimongo](https://www.meteor.com/mini-databases) as the default database.

NetBeans is the IDE I like, and am using for the HTML, CSS and JavaScript without a problem.

I'd like to be able to query the Meteor's MongoDB instance using NetBean's database GUIs as well; I don't know if any of NetBeans' standard DB views support MongoDB, but I have installed the [NBMongo](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/52638/nbmongo) plugin, which adds a view for MongoDB, and have other integration troubles covered.

My problem is that I don't know how to connect to the Meteor's MongoDB (/minimongo) from the NetBeans plugin.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

When you run `meteor mongo` on the shell/command-prompt, one of the things it will tell you is which address and port the Meteor's instance of the MongoDB is being run on. ***This is the key point I missed.***

In most cases, as I was seeing in the references I found online, this will be `127.0.0.1:3001`, or `localhost:3001`.

This wasn't the case for me, and that was why I was having trouble to setup my connection configuration.

I configured the NBMongo plugin's connection to `mongodb://[correct address]:[correct port]`, and *voilà*! Everything's working like a Swiss clock again!